# Ubuntu 20.04 after update from 18.04 does not prompt for login on booting

Tags: boot, login, 20.04, auto-login

I recently updated from ubuntu 18.04 to 20.04

I did this using `sudo do-release-upgrade` . On booting up I get auto-logged into the machine.
Can someone please help me figure this out. Will be glad to share any required file and configs.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `cat /etc/X11/default-display-manager ` please.

Comment: `/usr/sbin/lightdm`  sorry for the delay

Comment: Let us grep. `grep -ri auto /usr/share/lightdm/ /etc/lightdm/`

Comment: /usr/share/lightdm/guest-session/setup.sh:  if [ -e /etc/xdg/autostart/${service} ]; then
/usr/share/lightdm/guest-session/setup.sh:    [ -f ${HOME}/.config/autostart/${service} ] || cp /etc/xdg/autostart/${service} ${HOME}/.config/autostart
/usr/share/lightdm/guest-session/setup.sh:    echo "X-GNOME-Autostart-enabled=false" >> ${HOME}/.config/autostart/${service}
/usr/share/lightdm/guest-session/skel/.config/autostart/guest-session-startup.desktop:Exec=/usr/lib/lightdm/guest-session-auto.sh
/etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf:autologin-user=username

Answer (score 1, accepted):

search in

```
/etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf
```

for string

```
autologin-user=username
```

and comment this out.

```
#autologin-user=username
```

you need granted right.